# Running Tails from a non-writable CD vs a USB on a PC with a UEFI infection. Would it comprimise Tails OS when loaded?

Tags: rootkits, firmware

Lets say a computers UEFI is infected with a rootkit and you have a copy of Tails written to a USB drive.  I am guessing it could possibly infect the Tails OS as well.  Well if you were to write tails to a CD that is not re-writable and booted it up on the infected Machine I am guessing that it makes no difference right?  I mean the CD would not be infected, but the OS is loaded into RAM so the rootkit would still gain access to the OS when loaded right?

Comment: Maybe. I'm not a Tails expert, but unless you have a way to detect tampering with the TPM (e.g. a puri.sm key) I don't see how you plan to validate anything anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The only person who could answer this is the author of a particular piece of BIOS malware.

There is no way to rewrite a CD-ROM.

Could it infect the ram of Tails OS?  Sure, if it's smart enough.  Maybe not if it's targeted at Windows and can't infect Linux meaningfully.  Maybe not if  it's targeted at modifying hard drives and would fail because this one is in ram.

Answer (score 0):

[finspy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FinFisher) is a cross platform bootkit that has potential to do it

Comment: Can you explain why? Has there been instances of it doing this particular thing in the past? We need a little more meat on the bone of this answer.